# Deleting a sub organization

Tags: google-provisioning-api

I am running into an issue when I try to delete sub organizations.

I get the following error (customer ID was removed)

Execution of request failed: https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/orgunit/2.0/CustId/QA%2ftesting%2fmoar%2bgroups"}

I am using the Google Apps C# Library and calling it like this

OrgService.DeleteOrganizationUnit(customerID, "QA/testing/moar+groups");

The response body is "1301: Entity Does not exist"

I am taking the path directly from the feed to get all the organizations and passing it into delete and it is still failing... any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the name of the OU "QA/testing/moar+groups" or is it "QA/testing/moar groups"? You should be passing the true name of the OU to the library, it should take care of URL encoding it.

Comment: It actually looks like that is the issue... it is encoding the slashes, which isn't supposed to happen.  I tested this by going into the code in https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/ and removing the encoding that was happening after and getting it to delete.  The slashes should not be encoded